# Python print function stopped working after installing super-gradients in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

After installing super-gradients with different ways in Google Colab including `!pip install -qq super_gradients==3.5` and importing it, the python print() function stopped working and calling it resulted in no displaying output.

Comment: what do you mean "stopped working"? This seems very strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested many methods to solve the problem. The only thing that worked for me was use of `sleep(1)` after each `print()`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is because the module "super_gradients" seems to be capturing the stdout.

Here's the solution that worked for me:

```
stdout = sys.stdout
from super_gradients.training import models  
sys.stdout = stdout
print("hello")
```

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Consider taking the [tour].